# How to recieve data from a ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am new to ajax/jquery and I am trying to send a variable with a post request with ajax/jquery to the server and then console log it.

But for some reason when I console log it again from the server it stays undefined, so how do I properly send it off and retrieve it?

Code inventory.js:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function() {

  var temp = {test: 0}

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/inventoryactionbtn',
    data: temp,
    success: function(data) {
      //do something with the data via front-end framework
    }
  });

  return false;
})
```

Index.js:

```js
router.post('/inventoryactionbtn',  ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var testing= req.body
  console.log(testing)
})
```

Comment: the `{temp:0}` variable is available on processing request to `inventory`, not to `inventoryactionbtn`

Comment: I changed the url to: '/inventoryactionbtn'  but now it just gives me a empty {} .  How could i fix that?

Comment: where did you changed it? in you post I see `url: '/http://localhost:5000/inventory'`

Comment: In my visual studio code project :). And now also in the post.

Comment: So how do i fix the empty {} then?

Answer (score -1):

There are three problems:

## You aren't running your client-side JS

> ```
> $('inventoryactionbtn')
> ```

Will match `<inventoryactionbtn>` elements which aren't allowed in HTML. Probably you intended that to be an ID or class selector so you need the appropriate prefix.

`submit` events only fire on `<form>` elements so since you are targetting something with `btn` in the name, you are probably targetting the wrong element anyway.

## You need a body parsing middleware

See [the API reference](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body):

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is `undefined`, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()`.

There's no sign of any body-parsing middleware in the code you've provided. You need to use some which matches the format of the data you are POSTing.

## You need to get the URL right

`/http://localhost:5000/inventory`, even if you remove the `/` at the front, doesn't match (wherever you have mounted the router +) `/inventoryactionbtn`

Comment: Okay so now i got these two added: var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})  But now i just recieve a empty {}. How do i fix that?

Comment: The external body-parser module is deprecated, use the one built into Express. Creating a body parser is pointless if you don't `use` it. See the API reference link in the answer for an example. You do still need to get the URL you are POSTing to to match the route.

Comment: Okay some i am using right now this: router.use(express.json()) and
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })).  I changed the inventoryactionbtn to form but i still get a empty {}.  What else i am i doing wrong here?